# how to create design thinking for universal android fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I'm now thinking how can I create android apps like following facts...

1. start page is gridview and number of columns display will be based
   on device screen resolution
2. when I click one item on gridview,
   following screen will be display based on device resolution

   if phone or 7.0 tablet, screen will display with viewpager style.

   if 10 tablet, screen will display with two fragments style as follow

[image]

In that case, I don't want to create so many activity files for universal device. Eg, if phone or 7.0 tablet, go normalactivity.java. if 10 device, go hdactivity.java. What I want is whatever device, go detailactivity.java.

Is that possible?

Comment: Your question looks beautiful, complements on the pictures, but it's not clear what you want... The answer is either YES (and nothing else), or would require a book. Can you narrow it down and show us what you've tried. Some code would go a long way in getting a relevant answer.

Comment: for detail view, what I want is if device is phone phone, viewpager will be displayed(file should be detail.java) and device is tablet, two fragement view like above image will be displayed(file should be detail.java either). I don't want to create two file for viewpager detail and two fragments detail.

Answer (score 1):

You should go through the [Develop application Supporting Tablets and Handsets](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html)

This document provides guidance that can help you create an application that offers a unique and optimized user experience on both handsets and tablets, using fragments and the action bar.